# Observable pipe not called when source Observable is updated

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-observables, rxjs-observables

I have two Observables, one depends on data from the other.

When the data on the first Observable is changed it should update the second Observable.

Unfortunately, this is not working as I expect.

Here is the primary Observable (which works fine)

```js
export class LocaleService {
  locale$: Observable<string>;

  constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.locale$ = router.events.pipe(
      filter(evnt => envt instanceof ActivationEnd),
      map((evnt: ActivationEnd) => evnt.snapshot.paramMap.get('locale')),
      shareReplay(1),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the second Observable, which should update based on the value of the first Observable (seen above):

```js
// This type is more complex, but made it simple for demonstrating the problem
interface ICountries { code: string; }

export class DataService {
  countries$: Observable<ICountries>;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private localService: LocaleService) {
    this.localeService.locale$.subscribe(locale => {
      // this is only here for debug purposes, showing it does change
      console.log('changed locale', locale);
    });

    this.countries$ = localeService.locale$.pipe(
      tap(locale => { console.log('http updated', locale); }), // called first time only, not on locale changes...
      switchMap(locale => this.http.get<ICountries>(`http://localhost:8080/countries?lang=${locale}`)),
      shareReplay(1),
    );
  }
}
```

and if it matters, the way I am consuming the `countries$` is as follows (again, simplified to demonstrate the problem) :

```js
@Component({
  template: `<ng-container *ngIf="countries$ | async as countries">{{ countries.code }}</ng-container>`,
})
export class CountryComponent implements OnInit {
  countries$: Observable<ICountries>;

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {
    this.countries$ = dataService.countries$;
  }
}
```

I have been struggling with this for a few days now, looked for answers on StackOverflow, numerous other forums and asking friends who use Observables more frequently, but I cannot seem to solve this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @MichaelD correct, tap only gets called the first time and not after the locale$ changes. I tried removing `shareReply(1)` on LocaleService but that does not work, because DataService then does not get any updates. Or perhaps I misunderstood you?

Comment: have you tried deleting shareReplay(1) from local$ observable?

Comment: @FatehMohamed - MichaelD asked the exact same question, but then deleted his question. See my comment above your question.

Comment: Do you subscribe to your observable? Perhaps `dataService.countries$.subscribe();` somewhere that we can't see here? Really, `shareReplay(1)` should act sort of like subscribe(), (It should cause the stream to evaluate) but it really shouldn't be used that way. Just a guess though.

Comment: @MrkSef no subscribing outside of what you see, just a large data structure in the template. I tried adding an extra `.subscribe()` to `countries$` but it doesn't make a difference unfortunately.

Comment: The `this.countries` in the constructor should be `this.countries$` When you subscribe, to countries$ and console the result, does it go only once (same as tap)?

Comment: @MrkSef correct, sorry that was a typo I made when creating the simplified code for my question. I will update it shortly.

Comment: I made a version kinda like yours and it works just fine for me: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-rx-playground-cdstyg?file=index.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not exactly sure but you could try to split the observables to two different parts. At the moment it is single stream like below

```js
this.countries = localeService.locale$.pipe(
  tap(locale => { console.log('http updated', locale); }), // called first time only, not on locale changes...
  switchMap(locale => this.http.get<ICountries>(`http://localhost:8080/countries?lang=${locale}`)),
  shareReplay(1),
  tap(locale => { console.log('http updated', locale); }), // called first time only, not on locale changes...
  switchMap(locale => this.http.get<ICountries>(`http://localhost:8080/countries?lang=${locale}`)),
  shareReplay(1)
);
```

Here is my suggestion. I've just split the observable stream to two different streams using `ReplaySubject` with buffer 1 (the same as the `shareReplay` from the question)

**LocaleService**

```js
export class LocaleService {
  localeSource = new ReplaySubject<string>(1);
  locale$ = this.localeSource.asObservable();

  constructor(private router: Router) {
    router.events.pipe(
      filter(evnt => envt instanceof ActivationEnd),
      map((evnt: ActivationEnd) => evnt.snapshot.paramMap.get('locale'))
    ).subscribe(event => this.localeSource.next(event));
  }
}
```

**DataService**

```js
// This type is more complex, but made it simple for demonstrating the problem
interface ICountries { code: string; }

export class DataService {
  countriesSource = new ReplaySubject<ICountries>(1);
  countries$ = this.countriesSource.asObservable();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private localeService: LocaleService) {
    this.localeService.locale$.pipe(
      tap(locale => { console.log('http updated', locale); }),
      switchMap(locale => this.http.get<ICountries>(`http://localhost:8080/countries?lang=${locale}`))
    ).subscribe(countries => this.countriesSource.next(countries));
  }
}
```

**CountryComponent**

```js
@Component({
  template: `<ng-container *ngIf="(countries$ | async) as countries">{{ countries?.code }}</ng-container>`,
})
export class CountryComponent implements OnInit {
  countries$: Observable<ICountries>;

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {
    this.countries$ = this.dataService.countries$;
  }
}
```

Comment: I imagine you meant to remove `this.locale$ = ` and `this.countries$ = `?
Regardless, I tried this, it sounded good on paper, but unfortunately I still get the exact same result.

Comment: @JustinN: You're right. I forgot to remove the assignments in service constructors. I've updated the answer. So you mean the `switchMap` is triggered in the `DataService` but the `tap` isn't?

Comment: I mean that both DataService sees the first value from `locale$`, but it never receives the updates (neither `tap` nor `switchMap`). However, if I add localService.locale$.subscribe(console.log) - I see that locale$ does in fact change, it just never cascades through to the DataServices's pipe methods.

Comment: That sounds weird.

Comment: Very much so, and kind of why I decided to try SO for help as I can't figure it out, nor can anybody else I ask... 

Comment: I have played with it a bit more, and have discovered that everything works if it's inside the same class, however the moment it is split across two classes it does not work... Makes no sense to me, but maybe there is something I need to do for that to work? 

EDIT
Correction, it seems to be the switchMap preventing an update coming through.

Comment: After further investigating, it seems your code works just fine - the issue is that on some of the locales I am using for the http, I am getting an error back (endpoints do not exist yet, I was checking the failing request URLs were what I expected them to be).

So I needed to add a catchError onto my http, as that was preventing updates coming through.

Your answer did however solve my original issue, and made the code a fair amount cleaner, so I will be accepting it.

Thank you for the help and your time!

Comment: @JustinN: You're welcome :). Glad the issue got solved. Do check if your original code works as well.